# Change selected items order and merge using Javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, splistitem, client-object-model

I am now able to get the selected list items and merge its contents. Is there a way to reorder the selected items before merge? Or is there a way to get the items in the order in which they are selected?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using CAML? If so you can perhaps both sort and group, although if you are manually processing data why not just do order as well? So much [lodash](https://lodash.com/) fun

Comment: Thanks @eirikb. I'm using javascript to merge the contents. I need something like numbering the list items and then merging based on numbering.

Comment: We probably should start a chat right away, I'm afraid your question is not concrete enough. Anyway, could you provide a gist/pastebin of data before transformation, and an example of data as you want it to be converted into - in JSON format?

Comment: I will explain the scenario that is need to be done:
1. We have list with number of items in it.
2. Select the necessary list items.
3. Reoder the items (either by drag and drop or giving the items a specific number to sort).
4. Button to merge the content of selected items (which is already built).